# How to get start and end index of group of 1's in a series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I've a series like below:

```
index value
0       0
1       1
2       1
3       1
4       0
5       0
6       1
7       1
8       0
9       1
10      0
11      0
12      1
13      1
14      0
```

and the expected output is:

```
index, start, end
0       1       3
1       6       7
2       9       9
3       12      13
```

How can I achieve this with pandas?

Comment: whats the logic to obtain that output? what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Create consecutive 1 groups by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and filtering with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) (`==`) and then aggregate [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html)
 and 
[`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
df = df.reset_index()
m = df['value'].eq(1)
g = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()[m]

df = df.groupby(g)['index'].agg([('start','first'),('end','last')]).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   start  end
0      1    3
1      6    7
2      9    9
3     12   13
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of lines using `pandas` using the index of [`pd.Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html):

```
# Difference between consecutive values. A -1 is an 'end', a 1 is a 'start'
df_diff = df.diff()
df_res = pd.DataFrame()
df_res['start'] = df_diff[df_diff==1].index
df_res['end'] = df_diff[df_diff==-1].index -1

# Result
df_res
#   start  end
#0      1    3
#1      6    7
#2      9    9
#3     12   13
```

---

Note: `df` generated using:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.Series({0:0,1:1,2:1,3:1,4:0,5:0,6:1,7:1,8:0,9:1,10:0,11:0,12:1,13:1,14:0})
```